# droidcam not working on ubuntu 22.04 LTS in uefi mode

Tags: 22.04, droidcam

When I run the command `sudo ./install-video` this error appears

```
Registering webcam device
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Operation not permitted
warning: insmod failed
```

---

complete output:

```
sudo ./install-video                              
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make: Entrando no diretório '/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build M=/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback modules
make[1]: Entrando no diretório '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o
  MODPOST /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Saindo do diretório '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
make: Saindo do diretório '/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
Secure Boot is enabled, attempting to sign the driver
Copying file
+ cp v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/
+ set +x
Registering webcam device
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Operation not permitted
warning: insmod failed
Running depmod
make: Entrando no diretório '/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build M=/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback clean
make[1]: Entrando no diretório '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
  CLEAN   /tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback/Module.symvers
make[1]: Saindo do diretório '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
make: Saindo do diretório '/tmp/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
Done
```

when opening the program this message appears

[droidcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PacKN.png)

any idea what i can do?

Comment: On my 22.04 system, the location for that driver is /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback.ko

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Disable Secure Boot
I reinstalled v4l2loopback

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms cmake nasm yasm pkg-config libgtk2.0-dev
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
v4l2-ctl --list-devices     # check if you have dummy video devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video0
```